# Why isn't @node.Url working?

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco

I created this simple nav bar, and everything is working great except the URLs for the links. When I click on the links, it just gives me "#" after the current page's url, so the links look great but go nowhere. So I assume that @node.Url isn't working for some reason. Any ideas?

```
 <ul>

     @{

         var homeNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("Homepage");

     }

     @foreach (var node in homeNode.Children.Where("Visible"))

     {

         <li>

             <a href="@node.Url">@node.AsDynamic().Name</a> |

         </li>

     }

 </ul>
```

Comment: Looks like a data issue. Have you put a breakpoint in the controller to see where its coming from?

Comment: Which version umbraco?

Comment: @wingyip It says it's 7.2.0 but I thought I upgraded it properly to 7.2.2 a week ago.

Comment: @beautifulcoder I am actually coding directly from the Umbraco back end, so I don't think there's a way to do that there?

Comment: @everyone I think that this is actually related to a broader issue I'm having, as now I can't get to my doctypes either. I'm trying to find out more here - https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/61997-Why-isnt-@nodeUrl-working?p=0#comment210964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was happening was because of a database error related to nested doctypes. The way I solved it was to completely reinstall Umbraco 7.2.2, and then download the dev version of the next Umbraco version. Then I had to build the dev version, in order to get the resulting umbraco.core.dll and copy it into my own /bin/ folder. After doing this, my code worked perfectly, as well as fixing a number of other errors. If anyone else is experiencing this, the steps to fix it may be found here: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/60101-Upgrade-to-721-Document-Types-Break

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue directly related to the upgrade.

Assuming you took a backup of the code and database before performing the upgrade, I would recommend rolling back to the backups and updating again, being sure to follow the specific instructions supplied in the [upgrade guide](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/installation/upgrading/general)

Comment: The installation was a fresh 7.0.0 that had just been sitting there before I upgraded, so no, I didn't back it up.  I worked on the site for a week after doing this with no problems.

Comment: It turned out to be a database issue that neither I nor my colleagues were able to fix. Had to completely reinstall Umbraco. =(